# How to make ECR repository public?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, containers, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

How to make an ECR repository public for anybody to pull from. I see the policy document in the permission sections is where I should make permission changes. But it's not working, and I still need to get authenticated with the IAM user.

[image: Permission Options]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Amazon just released support for public ECR repositories!

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-ecr-public-a-new-public-container-registry/

Answer (score 16):

Amazon ECR currently supports private images. See official AWS ECR FAQ:

https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/faqs/

> Q: Can Amazon ECR host public container images?
>
> Amazon ECR currently supports private images. However, using IAM resource-based permissions, you can configure policies for each repository to allow access to IAM users, roles, or other AWS accounts.

You can use Docker Hub or other public repositories.

https://hub.docker.com/

Comment: Yes I have a dockerhub account. its for some other proj I need ECS repo. 
Only problem for me is to get the 'get ecr login' thing working when I need to pull from it. It then prompts for one more login when I do. Something I can't automate. Any ideas?

Comment: ECR's token expires for 12 hours. So, if you want to use `docker pull` in your scripts, login every time before pull. `$(aws ecr get-login) && docker pull` .

Answer (score 6):

check out https://github.com/monken/aws-ecr-public. It's a solution that provisions a serverless API Gateway to make ECR repositories public. It also supports custom domains.